# How to use Firebase Authentication with Okta?

Tags: firebase-authentication, openid-connect, okta

I am currently using Firebase Authentication in my app using the built-in OIDC providers (Google, Facebook etc.). Is it possible to use Okta as an additional OIDC provider with minimal modifications to my app, meaning Okta should behave just like any other built-in provider? Firebase Auth apis, such as `firebase.auth().currentUser` and `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` should still work.

The doc page for [Custom Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) talks about getting a custom token from an auth server, but does not clarify if that's an OAuth access token. Is there an example of Okta integration or a generic OIDC integration that works seamlessly with Firebase auth?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built-in Okta provider for Firebase Authentication, but if you have an existing authentication flow for it, it's fairly easy to integrate it into Firebase as a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

It's a 6 step process:

1. You gather the user credentials on the client.
2. You pass those credentials to a trusted environment, either a server you control, or Cloud Functions.
3. On the server you verify that the credentials are correct according to Okta, typically by calling a server-side API they provide with a key you provide.
4. You then use the results of that call to [mint a new ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) for the user. This is a JWT, not an OAuth access token.
5. You pass back that ID token from the server to the client.
6. The client then calls [`firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) with the ID token, to sign in to Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Frank. But doesn't collecting the user credentials create a  big security hole? The whole point of OIDC is not to have to deal with credentials directly. I was hoping that I could do something like this: run through [Okta's OIDC Code Flow with PKCE](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-overview/#authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) and then provide the returned OAuth access token and/or ID token to firebase to make this work. The goal is to be able to access Firebase resources (real-time DB, etc) using a proper Firebase user.

Comment: Credentials in this case wasn't meant as username+password, but whatever Okta gives you after authenticating the user. It's probably the equivalent of an OAuth token or an ID token. If you take the steps I describe with that, you get a Firebase user, which is then also present in the security rules for the database.

Comment: Awesome! Let me give that a shot. A couple of quick questions: 1) In your step 4, when I call `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)`, is a real firebase user created - meaning will I see a user in the Firebase console? 2) Is there a way to avoid cloud functions in step 2? My understanding is that the PKCE flow was designed to avoid calling any backend services.

Comment: 1) Good question. I'm actually not sure if the user will show up in the Firebase Authentication console. Give it a try and let me know.  2) Minting a custom token requires a trusted environment, otherwise anyone could mint custom tokens. PKCE can work without that, but you need the trusted environment to convert the Okta token to a Firebase JWT/ID token.

Comment: Running into an error in my cloud function to create a custom token: "IAM API has not been used in project <projectid> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam.googleapis.com/overview?project=<projectid>". When I visit this URL, I get an error "You are missing at least one of the following required permissions: Project resourcemanager.projects.get, serviceusage.services.get". I am the owner of the project, so don't understand this error.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am now able to call `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)` without any errors. Had to enable IAM API and grant `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permission to the service account. The [Troubleshooting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#troubleshooting) section was helpful. BTW, uid supplied to the `createCustomToken(uid)` is the same uid returned in the JWT. There is no user created in the Authentication console. Now I need to work on step 3 to verify credentials provided by Okta.

Comment: Minor correction - a real user is not created when `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)` is called in the cloud function. However when I call `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)` in the client, a real user is created - I can even see it in the Firebase console.

Comment: Cool, that's good to hear Naresh. I always forget whether custom tokens show up, but I guess it makes sense that they do once you use the token to sign in. Now let's see if I can remember it for next time. :)